# Nightwatch.js click() method not triggering event change in v-model

Tags: vue.js, nightwatch.js

I have run into an issue using the nightwatch.js `.click()` method where it is able to click on the dropdown selector and then the option populating the dropdown correctly, however attached to this 'changing' of the dropdown is a v-model that should then trigger some other js method to populate another dropdown depending on what was selected on the first.

For some reason using nightwatch doesn't trigger this event listener at all meaning the option within the first dropdown is selected but nothing gets set in the second. I can get it working no problem if I select it manually as it picks up that the dropdown has changed, but it will not work using `.click()` at all.

The project is written using Vue.js.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find the solution to solve this problem ?